# how to set object object inside the object in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to set object inside the object having some key .

```
 var item = {};
  item[inputItem.text] : sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.text);
```

I am getting error . of : in my  given line
     when I take this it take as string

```
item[inputItem.text] = sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.text);
```

Comment: What is `inputItem.text`?

Comment: it is key .i get object from key

Comment: What is the data in `sessionStorage`? What does the `getItem` method of sessionStorage return? What is the value of `inputItem.text`? Figuring out what you want without details is difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stored item is JSON, as your comment implies, `JSON.parse()` will turn it into a JavaScript object:

```
item[inputItem.text] = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.text) );
```

Comment: from this it is taking as string

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any sample data; assuming valid JSON, see my edited answer.